# Launching instagram App through instagram's in app browser

Tags: php, html, instagram, inappbrowser

```
<a href="instagram://user?username=someuser">Launch intagram</a>
```

Does work from google chrome on android phone. But not from instagram's In app browser. It shows 'Page can't be loaded'.

More explanation: I have sign in with instagram. Which takes me to the instagram's in app browser instead of phone browser. and then i am trying to launch instagram app if installed.

couldn't find anything anywhere. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think that the Instagram in-app browser doesn't support intents and it's not full featured like chrome.

For example it doesn't starts download any file and use external browser for direct download links.

U should use a global link for that:

http://instagram.com/someuser/

or

http://instagram.com/_u/someuser